# setting up an access point from laptop to provide internet

Tags: networking, internet, router, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

i am trying to connect my wireless router as an access point from my laptop. the scenario is as follows:
i have a wireless broadband connection at home, which i connect to using a username and a password. this username and password is unique, and can be used by one computer at a time!.. my sister and i can't have internet both at the same time! so im trying to connect my wireless router to my laptop with a physical cable so that i can provide internet via WiFi...

first off, is this possible?!.. if not, what are my options?

if it is possible, how do i set it up?

a link to the appropriate steps would do as well, but i need it :(...

thank you in advance,
/av

Comment: Mac or PC?  On a Mac, I'd check Finder's Apple Menu | System Preferences | Sharing | Network sharing to see whether your Wireless Broadband device shows up as something you can share.  Then you'd share it out your wired ethernet connection, which would go to your Wifi access point's uplink (or Internet) jack.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless router probably has a setting on the initial setup screen for PPoE connections which is what you need to get the router to login to the service for you then you can share the internet connection.  Your router probably has DHCP for the current WAN setting.  Change it to PPoE and you will get a place to put your login ID and password and have the router auto connect.

Comment: +1 for PPPoE although you missed one of the p's in the acronym. Essentially, the protocol provides connection tunneling over ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Some free products that can turn a computer into a hotspot:

[**Bzeek**](http://www.bzeek.com/static/index.html)

> Bzeek upgrades your laptop to be a
>   software access point for free.
>   When Bzeek is on, a wireless network
>   appears with the name 'Bzeek Free
>   WiFi'.

[**Connectify**](http://connectify.me/)

> **Software Based WiFi Router**
>  Take any Internet connection and share
>   it wirelessly with no additional
>   hardware, wires, plugs, or chargers
>   **Connect with Mobile Devices**
>  Easily connect any number of WiFi
>   enabled devices to your network
>   including laptops, phones, gaming
>   systems, and more
>   **Absolutely Free and Unrestricted**

[**2hotspot**](http://download.cnet.com/2hotspot/3000-2654_4-10495884.html)
Advertised for XP. Some report it as not working.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting of from LAN cables is possible, and you must remember to allow sharing of internet through this pc option in the network adapter for LAN in the contol panel.

Another option would be connecting to your router via LAN and set up ad hoc from your pc to allow your sister to connect wirelessly to you.

But I am curious why your wireless router only allow a single connection?